# Vuforia Engine Initialization Error: License Config Invalid Key

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I need help with Vuforia Engine in Unity. After Unity is done building and running my apps on android, I keep getting messages like this telling me that my license key is wrong or invalid.

error message

[image: 1]

Since then, I've made a new license key and replaced it in the Vuforia configuration numerous times, but I keep getting the same error.

Vuforia Configuration

vuforia Configuration

[image: 2]

My Software:

- Unity 2021.3.20f1
- Vuforia 10.13.3